# In Grid Layout, is it possible to change a row based on the class?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible in CSS Grid Layout to modify the template for say a specific row or column without having to rewrite the grid? Something like this:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
      "a a"
      "b b";
}
.grid .grid.row-2 {
    grid-template-row-2: "b a";
}
```

Comment: note that changing the second row to `b a` will make the template invalid as you will have the `a` a non rectangular shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate this using CSS variables:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      var(--row1,"a a")
      var(--row2,"b b");
      
    grid-auto-columns:40px;
    grid-auto-rows:40px;
    margin:10px;
}
.grid.row-2 {
    --row2:"b c";
}

.a {
  grid-area:a;
  background:red;
}

.b {
  grid-area:b;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid row-2">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - you can use `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start

Or even `grid-row: 1 / span 2;`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row

So you'd do something like this:

```css
.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid .row-2 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row-2">Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```